# 25 point FFT equations?

Tags: algorithms, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

I was going to attempt to study up on various papers like this one:

One Million-Point FFT (Hans Kanders and Tobias Mellqvist)

https://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1184623/FULLTEXT01.pdf

to try and come up with the equations for a 25-point FFT algorithm. 
But, before I went about doing that I figured I'd ask here if anyone just happened to already have the equations for a 25-point FFT or better yet a general N-point FFT that I can use to create an algorithm?

It seems like I just have to plug in 25 for N in the paper I linked (section 2.1.3), but I'm not sure.